# Flutter create widget based on figma to code plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a figma design on which I used figma to code plugin. Here's the [link](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/842128343887142055/Figma-to-Code-(HTML%2C-Tailwind%2C-Flutter%2C-SwiftUI)). As you can expect the plugin doesn't generate `Buttons`, `TextFields` or any other widgets. It only generates texts.

Now I have got this code from Figmna for my email field:

```
Container(
   width: 327,
   height: 56,
   child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
         children: [
              SizedBox(
                 width: 327,
                 height: 56,
                     child: Material(
                         color: Color(0xfff8f8fa),
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                         child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                               left: 24,
                                  right: 178,
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "sag7@gmail.com",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xff18172b),
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        fontFamily: "Poppins",
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                          ),
                     ),
             ),
       ],
   ),
),
```

I need to convert this into text box. Now this is what I've tried so far instead of row:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
  ),
);
```

But I don't want the border and when I turn the `Text` into TextField it just gives me a simple underlined text field when I want to convert the entire container to be a text field.

What am I missing here?

this is a visual example of what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the underline for your `TextField` you need to use `InputBorder.none` and not `UnderlineInputBorder()`.

About the layout you try to implement I've made a really basic code sample which you can try to edit to obtain the result you want.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

You can use the text fields and click on the `Signin` and `Register` buttons are clickable.

**Full code used in the example:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Widget _buildEmailField() => Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
        ),
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildPasswordField() => Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
        ),
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
          obscureText: true,
          style: TextStyle(
            letterSpacing: 5.4,
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildLabel(String label) => Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
          child: Text(label, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildButton() => Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
        ),
        child: TextButton(
          child: Text('Signin', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          onPressed: () => print('Signin'),
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildRegisterBtn() => Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => print('Register'),
          child: Text(
            "Don't have an account? Register",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        children: [
          _buildLabel('Email'),
          _buildEmailField(),
          _buildLabel('Password'),
          _buildPasswordField(),
          const SizedBox(height: 28),
          _buildButton(),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          _buildRegisterBtn(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Try the code on DartPad](https://gist.github.com/TesteurManiak/56ed9085569025bb79842721d2403935)